# iphone 3.1.2 sdk UIImagePicker for type movie not copying a thumbnail

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ffmpeg, uiimagepickercontroller

I have seen this question pop up a few times but the authors see to be satisfied with the wrong answer, so I will ask again.

When picking a movie out of the user's gallery, I am given a MOV in the tmp directory but I am not given the thumbnail for the movie now in the 3.1+ sdk. In sdk 3.0, you get a jpg in the tmp folder but this behavior has stopped.

Is there an answer to get the thumb besides ffmpeg? Anything supported by the sdk?

I get a thumb when they shoot a video directly.

This answer is wrong: [iphone sdk > 3.0 . Video Thumbnail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259316/iphone-sdk-3-0-video-thumbnail)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, but I had to wait until iOS4 (the feature came out in 3.2)

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    if ([mediaType compare:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie] == NSOrderedSame) {
        // deal with the movie
        [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        NSURL *mediaUrl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        NSLog(@"media Url = %@, path %@", mediaUrl, [mediaUrl path]);
        MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:mediaUrl];
        UIImage *thumbnail = [[moviePlayer thumbnailImageAtTime:0.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame] retain];
        [moviePlayer release];
        NSLog(@"thumbnail = %@", thumbnail);
        [thumbnail release];
    }
}
```

Comment: thumbnailImageAtTime deprecated for iOS 7, What should i do??? (By deprecated Apple policy Apple support deprecated code up to 3 years, But it means that in the next 3 years i must change my code if i want to update my app in the app store), help please ??