# How to extract images from a video?

Tags: ios, image, video, uiimagepickercontroller

can anyone tell me how to extract images from a video? what i ve tried till now is i ve follow these:

- [Getting iPhone video thumbnails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171086/getting-iphone-video-thumbnails)
- [Getting a thumbnail from a video url or data in iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347562/getting-thumbnail-from-a-video-url-or-data-in-iphone-sdk)
- [How do I extract a screenshot from a video in the iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201399/how-do-i-extract-a-screenshot-from-a-video-in-the-iphone-sdk)
- [iPhone Read UIimage (frames) from video with AVFoundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199879/iphone-read-uiimage-frames-from-video-with-avfoundation) , [iphone sdk > 3.0 . Video Thumbnail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259316/iphone-sdk-3-0-video-thumbnail/1301311#1301311)

etc. and after that i ve done this:

**Source Code:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    videoPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [videoPicker setDelegate:self];
    videoPicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    NSArray *mediaTypesAllowed = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    videoPicker.mediaTypes = mediaTypesAllowed;
    videoPicker.view.hidden = YES;
}


-(IBAction)imgPickerController
{
    [self presentModalViewController:videoPicker animated:YES];
    videoPicker.view.hidden = NO;
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // e.g.
    NSString *tempFilePath = [(NSURL *)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] absoluteString];

    NSLog(@"didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: %@",tempFilePath);

    // e.g. /private/var/mobile/Applications/D1E784A4-EC1A-402B-81BF-F36D3A08A332/tmp/capture/capturedvideo.MOV
    tempFilePath = [tempFilePath substringFromIndex:16];

    NSLog(@"didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: %@",tempFilePath);
    NSLog(@"===Try to save video to camera roll.===");
    NSLog(@"UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum: %@",UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(tempFilePath)? @"YES":@"NO");

    // Check if the video file can be saved to camera roll.
    if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(tempFilePath))
    {
        // YES. Copy it to the camera roll.
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(tempFilePath, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:),(__bridge_retained void *)tempFilePath );
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)video:(NSString *)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(NSString *)contextInfo
{
    NSLog(@"didFinishSavingWithError--videoPath in camera roll:%@",videoPath);
    NSLog(@"didFinishSavingWithError--videoPath in temp directory:%@",contextInfo);

    // The thumbnail jpg should located in this directory.
    NSString *thumbnailDirectory = [[contextInfo stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];

    // Debug info. list all files in the directory of the video file.
    // e.g. /private/var/mobile/Applications/D1E784A4-EC1A-402B-81BF-F36D3A08A332/tmp/capture
    NSLog(@"%@",[contextInfo stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[contextInfo stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] error:nil] description]);

    // Debug info. list all files in the parent directory of the video file, i.e. the "~/tmp" directory.
    // e.g. /private/var/mobile/Applications/D1E784A4-EC1A-402B-81BF-F36D3A08A332/tmp
    NSLog(@"%@",thumbnailDirectory);
    NSLog(@"%@",[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:thumbnailDirectory error:nil] description]);
    ///////////////////

    // Find the thumbnail for the video just recorded.
    NSString *file,*latestFile;

    NSDate *latestDate = [NSDate distantPast];
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:[[contextInfo stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]];

    // Enumerate all files in the ~/tmp directory
    while (file = [dirEnum nextObject])
    {
        // Only check files with jpg extension.
        if ([[file pathExtension] isEqualToString: @"jpg"]) 
        {
            NSLog(@"***latestDate:%@",latestDate);
            NSLog(@"***file name:%@",file);
            NSLog(@"***NSFileSize:%@", [[dirEnum fileAttributes] valueForKey:@"NSFileSize"]);
            NSLog(@"***NSFileModificationDate:%@", [[dirEnum fileAttributes] valueForKey:@"NSFileModificationDate"]);

            // Check if current jpg file is the latest one.
            if ([(NSDate *)[[dirEnum fileAttributes] valueForKey:@"NSFileModificationDate"] compare:latestDate] == NSOrderedDescending)
            {
                latestDate = [[dirEnum fileAttributes] valueForKey:@"NSFileModificationDate"];
                latestFile = file;
                NSLog(@"***latestFile changed:%@",latestFile);
            }
        }
    }

    // The thumbnail path.
    latestFile = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:latestFile];
    NSLog(@"****** The thumbnail file should be this one:%@",latestFile);

    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:latestFile];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 150, 100, 100)];
    [imgView setImage:img];
    imgView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];

    // Your code ...
    // Your code ...
    // Your code ...
}
```

After doing all this still i dint reached where i want to reach.i dint get images still.I'm stuck now.Pls anyone help me out!!!Thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simple way to extract thumbnails from a movie is to use `MPMoviePlayerController` class and its `- thumbnailImageAtTime:timeOption:` method.

For example you've got a filepath url:

```
NSURL *tempFilePathURL = ...;
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: tempFilePathURL];
UIImage *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:THUMBNAIL_TIME timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact];
[player release];
```

I used it in my code and it worked.

Comment: Can u pls tell me how can i get the path and extension of this thumbnail??

Comment: According to my example you'll get UIImage object. Then you can save it as png or jpg.

Answer (score 3):

**thumbnailImageAtTime:timeOption** is depricated since iOS 7.0.
Here is an alternative

```
+ (UIImage *)extractFirstFrameFromFilepath:(NSString *)filepath
{
    AVURLAsset *movieAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath] options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *assetImageGemerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:movieAsset];
    assetImageGemerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
    CGImageRef frameRef = [assetImageGemerator copyCGImageAtTime:CMTimeMake(1, 2) actualTime:nil error:nil];
    return [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:frameRef];
}
```

Comment: Can we rewrite this to go through the whole video? Or perhaps every 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift Version**

```
    func getThumbOfVideo(fileURL: URL) -> UIImage? {
        let movieAsset = AVURLAsset(url: fileURL)
        let assetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: movieAsset)
        assetImageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true

        var thumbnail: UIImage?
        do {
            let cgImage = try assetImageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(value: 0, timescale: 1000), actualTime: nil)
            thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        return thumbnail
    }
```

If you need **thumbnail array** throughout the video then use the following API of *AVAssetImageGenerator* class

```
func generateCGImagesAsynchronously(forTimes requestedTimes: [NSValue], 
                  completionHandler handler: @escaping AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler)
```

For required thumbnail image resolution set the following property

> assetImageGenerator.maximumSize