# Picking video from application and copy them in document directory

Tags: iphone, file, video, uiimagepickercontroller, mpmediapickercontroller

I was using `UIImagePickerController` to select the video files from Image Gallery of IPhone using

```
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
```

and that code is working fine and picker shows me all available videos in Gallery but the problem is that `UIImagePickerController` do not shows all videos of IPhone like videos on Video  folder of Iphone and also the synched videos on IPhone. In short it only shows video recorded from Iphone only. But my requirement  is to show all videos in Iphone and getting their path so that I can write them using `FileManager`.

I also tried using

```
MPMediaPickerController *picker =
    [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeAnyAudio];

    picker.delegate                     = self;
    picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems   = YES;
    picker.prompt                       = NSLocalizedString (@"AddSongsPrompt", @"Prompt to user to choose some songs to play");

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:YES];

    [self presentModalViewController: picker animated: YES];
    [picker release];
```

But it also shows me music files of Iphone not video.
Please some one has any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

try `initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeAnyVideo` instead of `initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeAnyAudio`

also see this link for more information, [MPMediaItem_ClassReference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MPMediaType)

Comment: Thanks Paras. Actually I made a mistake in posting the code sample. I used  initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeAnyVideo instead of initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeAnyAudio but still not working for me.I also looked at class reference but its not working for me.

Comment: hey @Abhinav see this link may you can find something from this.. http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/1980.. here for Music ..  just see where you wrong from this code.. :)

Comment: I am using same code just by changing initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeAnyVideo. :(

Comment: see this code with AssetLibrary http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390614/display-all-videos-stored-in-document-directory

Comment: hey @Abhinav just try to use this library and use it.. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/01_UsingAssets.html

Comment: I just found you post and want to ask you if you found a good solution. I am having a somewhat related issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57987133/trying-to-make-a-file-copy-from-mpmediapickercontroller-but. I know it's a long time ago :)