# How To edit frame of video, Edit that particular frame and replace it with actual frame in video?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

I am very upset because from last two days i am searching for editing video frame and replacing them at same time(frame actual time) with edited frame but i am unable to do that.
I have seen so many links of stackoverflow but that is not perfect for my requirement- iFrame extractor is not working.
[Get image from a video frame in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810764/get-image-from-a-video-frame-in-iphone)

In mean while, I though to extract all frames and save it in an array of dictionary with frames and respecting time and when i got a frame from running video then after editing i will run a loop for actual frame with respecting time and i will match the actual time with captured(edited frame running from video) frame and if it got then replace actual frame with edited frame and again write the video from all frames.

but to do so i used -
 [Get all frames of Video IOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436552/get-all-frames-of-video-ios-6)

but it is crashing after extracting some images .
I have written my code like this

```
 -(void)editMovie:(id)sender
   {

     float FPS=1;
     NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]   pathForResource:@"IMG_0879" ofType:@"MOV"];
     NSURL *videoURl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
     AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videoURl options:nil];
     AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    generator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter =  kCMTimeZero;
    generator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore =  kCMTimeZero;
   for (Float64 i = 0; i < CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration) *  FPS ; i++){
    @autoreleasepool {
        CMTime time = CMTimeMake(i, FPS);
        NSError *err;
        CMTime actualTime;
        CGImageRef image = [generator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:&actualTime error:&err];
        UIImage *generatedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image];
        [self saveImage: generatedImage atTime:actualTime]; // Saves the image on document directory and not memory
        CGImageRelease(image);
          }
      }

   }
-(void)saveImage:(UIImage*)image atTime:(CMTime)time
    {
      float t=time.timescale;
      NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
     [dict setObject:image forKey:@"image"];
     [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",t]  forKey:@"time"];
     [arrFrame addObject:dict];
     NSLog(@"ArrayImg=%@",arrFrame);

    }
```

My Requrement is ->>>

1. I need to run a video
2. From running video i have to pause a video and get image(frame) at pause time.
3. I have to edit captured image and save or replace at actual image.
   4 when i agin play the video the edited image should be in video.

Please give me any example if you all have, I have downloaded so many projects or examples from given link of stack flow or other sites but no one perfect or even fulfilling my 20 % requirement.

Please give me any example or ides if you have.

I will be obliged to you, Thanks in Advance

Comment: hey @Anuj Kumar Rai i want to do something like this here are the steps     
1. start play video file .
2. Pause Video at anytime & get the pause frame of video
3. edit that frame and save video 
4. now play saved video and edited frame will show up at that time where it was edited

Please let me know it is possible or not because i think you have done lots R&D in this scenario.